# How can I highlight syntax like it appears on stackoverflow?

Tags: posts, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I am writing a post and want to highlight only a couple of characters: `like this`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML language includes a [special tag for displaying inline code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code). To apply it to your text, switch to the 'Text' visual editor tab and place the `<code>` tag before your bit of code, and the `</code>` tag afterwards.

If you want to use the backtick ` character for highlighting code like you do on Stack Overflow, check out [this plugin by Tom McFarlin](http://tommcfarlin.com/markdown-code-for-wordpress/).

Comment: thanks great answer.we should always answer in WordPress way if their any.I'm a newbie and learning how to answer on stackoverflow or solve a problem in wordpress way.thanks again.

Comment: @Ravs this is the best way for WordPress and everything overall. You shouldn't try and emulate a `<code>` tag by using a `<span>` tag. And shortcodes are not supposed to be used for plain HTML, that's what HTML is for

Answer (score 0):

you can create a shortcode for this

```
<?php
add_shortcode('highlight','ravs_hightlight');
function ravs_hightlight( $atts, $content=""){
  return '<span class="highlight">'.$content.'</span>';
}
?>
```

paste above code in `functions.php`.

use shortcode in wordpress editer like

```
[highlight]test for hightlight short code[/highlight]
```

your html output like

```
<span class="highlight">test for hightlight short code</span>
```

give some css to `.highlight` class

**Important Link**:

[add_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Answer (score 0):

This subject has been successfully discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931162/wordpress-syntax-highlighting), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273647/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-a-wordpress-blog-hosted-on-wordpress-com).

Bungeshea is right, but you can also and simply add these tags in your text editor (not visual editor):

```
[sourcecode language='CorrespondingLanguage']
    //Your code goes here
[/sourcecode]
```

Comment: That is __not__ Core functionality. In order for that work a plugin, which you do not name, must be installed. Note: both links you post refer to wordpress.com which is a hosted platform that includes some functionality not bundled with the Core and which I have to assume is why that shortcode works on those sites. This is not a viable answer as written.

Comment: You're right in one point, the links refer to hosted platform, but after many posts readed, these short tags work also on non hosted wordpress sites without plugins... but I will check myself to be sure, thanks for answer @s_ha_dum

Comment: I have never known a `sourcecode` shortcode to be bundled with WordPress. You are mistaken.